# Modify List<T> object to work with method that receives <T> or viceversa in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list

I need some suggestion on how to fix my code. I'm working on some existing project which has a bunch of dependencies, so the less I have to modify, the better. In this case, my controller needs BuildingReportModel as LIST, and at the end this controller returns this list to some view. My issue is when I try to call GetWSObject which receives a model/class, no a LIST. How would be the best way or best practices to make this code work? BuildingReportModel needs to be declare as List<> since I have some previous validation that can't be changed. Any suggestions?

```
List<BuildingReportModel> rc = new List<BuildingReportModel>();

BuildingWSObjects ws = new BuildingWSObjects();
rc = await ws.GetWSObject<BuildingReportModel>("all");

return View(rc);


public class BuildingReportModel
{
    public string message1 { get; set; }
    public string message2 { get; set; }        
}


public class BuildingWSObjects
{
    public async Task<T> GetWSObject<T>(string uriActionString)
    {
        T returnValue =
            default(T);
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/logger");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uriActionString);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                returnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(((HttpResponseMessage)response).Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw (e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would modify `BuildingWSObjects` class and add new method:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetWSObjects<T>(string uriActionString)
{
    return  new List<T> { await this.GetWSObject<T>(uriActionString)};
}
```

Comment: Excellent! that works perfect! I'm marking this as answer. Thanks @Maksim

Comment: @RolandoF you did "+1 vote" instead of marking as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

pass list to your GetWSObject than it will return you a list.

```
rc = await ws.GetWSObject<List<BuildingReportModel>>("all");
```